# What could be causing this leak?

Tags: water, diy-vs-pro, leaks

Looked at my water meter, and noticed it was slowly running even though everything in the house was turned off upon inspecting around my home. Noticed there’s a leak that’s been steady growing the past week.
Does anyone know what could be causing this? Again everything in my home is turned off but this leak remains here.[image]

Comment: do you have a sprinkler system

Comment: Underground pipe between the meter and before it goes into the house.

Comment: You haven't said how much is actually leaking per minute; knowing that would help.

Comment: @keshlam I'm thinking the OP did not have a moat before this leak occurred.

Comment: Try to shut off the water mains. It's not in your house, it should be in the street or yard somewhere.

Comment: @adamo: I'm trying not to guess. If they clarify, great, otherwise the water outside is not especially likely to be relevant. In any case, that wouldn't change the process needed to find and fix the leak.

Answer (score 6):

You have a break in a pipe under the ground.
Start the dirty process of digging the ground up and you will get clues such as the ground drier in one direction compared to the other. Dig in the wetter direction and eventually you will find the leak.
Repairing it will be determined by what you find.

If you have or can get a mechanics stethoscope, you can sometimes probe the ground and hear where the water is "hissing" out of the break.

Good Luck

Comment: Agreed, leaking supply line.   But may or may not be able to detect where. messy job.

Answer (score 4):

Odds of dampness outside being related to the leak are pretty low. Not impossible -- leaked water has to go somewhere, after all -- but that wouldn't be where I'd start when trying to diagnose this.

Slow leaks at tank toilets are *very* common; the flap valve fails to seat properly, water level drops, the refill valve comes slightly open to bring the tank back up to expected level, lather, rinse, repeat. So the first thing I'd do is try turning off the feed to those and see if your leakage goes away (or greatly decreases), then turn them back on one at a time until you find the one that is making trouble. An easier alternative, to put off fiddling with the valves, may be to somehow prop the valve floats in a lifted position; that'll also let you see directly if the tank is slowly draining itself.

If that doesn't isolate the problem, then start working your way through the rest of the pipes on the divide-and-conquer principle:

- Establish the rate at which water is leaking.
- Follow the pipe after it leaves the master cut-off and meter.
- When you come to a valve, turn it off. Check the meter's flow rate.
- If turning that valve off doesn't change the flow rate, you know that the branch controlled by that valve isn't the cause of your problem. Go back to the junction(s) before that valve (I'm presuming there will be at least one) and follow the other branch(es) until you find a valve and test that one.
- Repeat until you find the valve that makes the leakage flow stop. Then turn that valve back on and follow the pipe from it forward, using the same trial-and-error process to establish which of *its* branches accounts for the unexpected flow.
- Repeat until you find the leakage point.